# How to restore a Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning to use Tensorflow and I wrote this Python script that learns from mnist db, save the model and make a prediction on a image:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10], name="W"))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="b")
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]), W) + b)
# ...
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # ... learning loop

    saver.save(sess, "/tmp/my-model")

    # Make a prediction with an image
    im = numpy.asarray(Image.open("digit.png")) / 255
    im = im[numpy.newaxis, :, :, numpy.newaxis]
    dict = {X: im}
    print("Prediction: ", numpy.array(sess.run(Y, dict)).argmax())
```

The prediction is correct, but I can't restore the saved model for reusing.
I wrote this other script that tries to restore the model and make the same prediction:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10]) / 10, name="b")
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]), W) + b)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/my-model.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/tmp/'))

    # Make a prediction with an image
    im = numpy.asarray(Image.open("digit.png")) / 255
    im = im[numpy.newaxis, :, :, numpy.newaxis]
    dict = {X: im}
    print("Prediction: ", numpy.array(sess.run(Y, dict)).argmax())
```

but the prediction is wrong.
How can I restore my variables and make a prediction?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When test, comment this line

```
# saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/my-model.meta')
```

will solve your problem.

`import_meta_graph` will create a new Graph/model saved in the '.meta' file and the new model will co-exist with the model you created manually. The `saver` is assigned to the new model, so `saver.restore` restores the trained weights to the new model, but the `sess` runs using the model you created manually.